# Querying JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I saw some questions about Quering JSON in python, but I didn't quite find what I was looking for.
I have two big files in a JSON format, where every line is a record, e.g

file 1:

```
{"x": 2, "y": 0}
{"x": 3, "y": 1}
{"x": 4, "y": 1}
```

file 2:

```
{"x": 5, "z": 0}
{"x": 4, "z": 1}
{"x": 4, "z": 1}
```

I input the files to python with

```
for line in infile:
      Review = json.loads(line)
```

After inserting the line to "review", i do extra actions to insert these records into a dict.

This takes quite some time because every file has around 100K rows.
Now, if I want to query these files (lets say, join by X) i have to loop through them again. I thought about using some kind of Sqlite package in python to do this, but it just seems too clumsy. 
Anyone have an idea what the most efficient way to do this is? 
Thanks.

Comment: I would start by working backwards... why do you have this data in such an unfriendly format for the desired end use to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean by unfriendly format? thats the way I got it... how can I make it friendlier?

Comment: If you want to be able to join this data, why have it reside in files rather than a database or similar to begin with? You likely don't want to read these files into memory everytime you want to use them.

Comment: You are right, but what is the easyest way of passing these files to a database?

Comment: I would imagine by using the python library for whatever your database of choice might be.

Comment: can you refer me to such?

Comment: I would imagine you might find plenty of documentation around how to install MySQL python on your OS of choice. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is in the python standard lib, so you already have it. You create your table in memory using (":memory:") instead of am ordinary connection string (details on the page linked above).

You're doing database style operations on large numbers of stuff and you want to do them quickly: that suggests (a) a database and (b) loading everything into memory.